# Fatal Error , website is down and throwing the error below

Tags: mysql, wordpress

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "MB_OVERLOAD_STRING"
> in
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Core/Util.php:915
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Core/Util.php(757):
> ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::isMbStringOverride() #1
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php(2822):
> ParagonIE_Sodium_Core_Util::strlen('G"\x18\xC5\xEA\xCF\xE4\x18\x19\x03\x89Vd/\x96...') #2 /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfCentralAPI.php(304):
> ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat::crypto_sign_detached('9c956ebc1196f7b...',
> 'G"\x18\xC5\xEA\xCF\xE4\x18\x19\x03\x89Vd/\x96...') #3
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfCentralAPI.php(253):
> wfCentralAuthenticatedAPIRequest->fetchToken() #4
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfCentralAPI.php(51):
> wfCentralAuthenticatedAPIRequest->getToken() #5
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wfCentralAPI.php(559):
> wfCentralAPIRequest->execute() #6
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287):
> wfCentral::sendSecurityEvent('adminLoginNewLo...', Array, Array) #7
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #8
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wordfenceClass.php(2501):
> do_action('wordfence_secur...', 'adminLoginNewLo...', Array, Array)
> #10 /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(289): wordfence::loginAction('Admin_BIT2') #11
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #12
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #13
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/user.php(110):
> do_action('wp_login', 'Admin_BIT2', Object(WP_User)) #14
> /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-login.php(1248): wp_signon(Array, true)
> #15 {main} thrown in /home/ogsweb/public_html/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Core/Util.php
> on line 915

Comment: Some more info about when the error started to appear, and what was changed might be helpful.

Comment: Yes , there was an upgrade from my host company server with php 7 and its upgraded to php 8.1. i had to backup my webfiles and migrated yesterday to the new server provision,since then i have been have some issues here and there. Please how do i resolve this

Comment: Find the module in your wordpress site that is responsible for this, and try to find another module that can work with PHP8. If you have not (enough) knowledge of PHP/Wordpress, then you might need to hire an expert.

Comment: [This](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/23/wordpress-and-php-8-0/) article, about "WordPress and PHP 8.0" from 1.5 year ago, already (could have) warned you. when you have a (runnig) wordpress site, you should know which modules you use, and always keep up with changes. This als means never "assume" it will be running after an update.

Comment: And, just using Google here, the bug you are facing now seems to have been solved **19** months ago, see: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51399

Answer (score 0):

On [Submit a Pull Request Report a Bug
Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php)  (when searching for "MB_OVERLOAD_STRING", you will find:

> The mbstring.func_overload directive has been removed. The related
> MB_OVERLOAD_MAIL, MB_OVERLOAD_STRING, and MB_OVERLOAD_REGEX constants
> have also been removed. Finally, the "func_overload" and
> "func_overload_list" entries in mb_get_info() have been removed.

This means your server did have an upgrade from PHP 7.4 to 8.0 , and throwing the error since then?

Comment: Yes , there was an upgrade from my host company server with php 7 and its upgraded to php 8.1. i had to backup my webfiles and migrated yesterday to the new server provision,since then i have been have some issues here and there. Please how do i resolve this